# Lost connection to iOS 8 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

I have a problem using Xcode 6 beta 4 and iOS 8 simulator. Each time I try to run my project Xcode sends me a "Connection lost" error. I tried to delete and create new simulator, set Command Line Tools for Xcode 6 and still nothing happened. what should I do?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the whole IDE?

Comment: It's actually pretty sad this 'Did you try turning it off and on again?' seems to solve this problem... :(

Comment: Of course I have :) Didn't solve the problem

Comment: Experiencing this also

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Not sure why you have added you own screenshot to the question. Please don't if the user has a screenshot of their issue they will provide one.

Comment: Has anyone faced this on a device? I face this, specifically on iPhone 6+. This crash occurs even when the device is not connected to the MAC.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020832/ios-app-crashes-xcode-says-lost-connection-to-xs-iphone-when-debugging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try to "Reset the content and Settings..." in iOS Simulator, it works for me. Currently my Xcode version is 6.0 (6A313).

This should be a known bug of iOS Simulator after searching, you could try the above the solution to fix it temporarily. Good luck!

***UPDATE***:
Before you try to reset the iOS Simulator, just quit (cmd + Q) and launch it, I found it works good in my simulator/xcode 6.1.1, too.

Answer (score 3):

Simply Re-Run your project. No need to do any other step.

Comment: I would like to know why it happens in the first place. Kind of a pain to have to run the app twice to run the app once.

Comment: Did not work for me, but Itachi's solution did

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is precisely one issue - the version of xcode you have is a beta, and this is a known bug.

A couple things to try to get it to work,

1. Restarting the Xcode and computer. For some reason, the bug pops up less frequently in my experience after the above steps are taken.
2. Ignore it. The app will sometimes run just fine, despite the error.
3. Redownload the dev tools. This might make it work if you have a corrupt version causing the bug to be more prevalent.
4. Wait for it to be fixed. It is still beta software - it should be fixed soon. Hopefully.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in my post on the iOS Simulator dev forums (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248879?tstart=0), this is one way in which a timing bug (failing race condition) exhibits itself.  The only real workaround at this point is to just retry.  Resetting contents and settings or rebooting is not really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my device fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This happens less frequently in Xcode 6.1 as compared to Xcode 6 beta version.
Only **solution is to Re-run your project**. This seems to be bug and might be fixed in upcoming Xcode 6.2 version.

This still occurs in Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app in the simulator, and run again. fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience nothing worked but using iOS V7.1

After restarting the simulator, and even the Mac the error persisted, so i had to download iOS V7.1 simulator and after that connection worked as expected with this version