# Debugging app on a specific device causes app to crash and Xcode to lose connection to device

Tags: ios, xcode, gpuimage, iphone-6-plus

We are testing our app on several iPhone 6 Pluses, and at some point we are using GPUImage to capture some images. On my device, it works fine, but on my friend's device, it causes app to crash and Xcode to lose connection to device. It's not like an exception where you hit a breakpoint. Connection to device is lost completely for a split second, just as we've quickly unplugged and replugged the lightning cable (no, we haven't, obviously). There are no errors or warnings at Xcode console, it's exactly like we've unplugged the device, therefore I have no idea why the error occurs. Other than that, the app works normally, and if there are crashes, it 'crashes' normally (hitting a breakpoint on Xcode normally). The bug apparently happens only on camera launch and/or when user takes a photo. Why would that happen? Is it a hardware issue (the device's camera works normally though), or if not, what can I do to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020832/ios-app-crashes-xcode-says-lost-connection-to-xs-iphone-when-debugging

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at any memory issues that may be causing the crash.  I'm having a similar problem and determined that I was having memory problems by assessing Allocations while profiling the app using Instruments:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html