# App crashes after third open of Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-cardboard

When I open my ViewController with a 360 video for cardboard for the third time I get the following error: 
"Lost connection to 'Iphone xxx'" See this Stack question: [iOS app crashes, xcode says 'Lost connection to X's iPhone' when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020832/ios-app-crashes-xcode-says-lost-connection-to-xs-iphone-when-debugging)

I am opening the ViewController like this:

```
PlayerViewController *cardboardViewController = [[PlayerViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:cardboardViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And canceling the view controller by dismissing it. The memory is not too bad with around 20 MB but there are around 10-15 threads what I wasnt able to reduce.

How can I destroy the view or reduce threads to prevent this app crash?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your code is fine did you try changing where your USB cable is plugged into? If it is plugged into a hub make sure its plugged directly into the machine.

Other than that we will need some more code.