# Lost connection to "iOS 9 simulator"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, uicollectionview

I have stopped all simulator processes but still getting below error.

> Restore the connection to "iPad 2" and run "APPNAME" again, or if
>   "APPNAME" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug >
>   Attach to Process > APPNAME.

Getting this error in Xcode 7.3.1, which is not consistent.

[image]

I have a `CollectionView` and into that, I want to show images from the document directory. So I am using `SDWebImage` SDK for that. So somehow this happens due to this line.

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myPathOfDocumentDirectory)
cell.myImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "background"))
```

Because when I put comment on line for set the image into `ImageView` via `SDWebImage` SDK, then app not getting crashed. Otherwise it will crash randomly. Also it happens in devices too. I have test this in many devices.

I have read many answers, but into all that answers, talking about reset the simulator. But this happens many times with me. So I want a solution for this.

**So Is there anyway to show images from document directory in `CollectionView`..?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Base on my experience this issue is `memory issue`. Review this answer also :-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020832/ios-app-crashes-xcode-says-lost-connection-to-xs-iphone-when-debugging

Comment: @mitulmarsonia : Yess that's the issue. So I have compress my images and showing them to collection view. And no crashes. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yess I got the solution. Thanks @mitulmarsonia for quick commenting on my question.

When loading a bunch of very large images (greater then 2000 or 3000 px) in UIImages, Luckily the images were not supposed to be anywhere near that big and I just needed to resize them.

Please resize of your images before saving them document directory if you want to show them into listings.

Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020832/3908884) for more details.